# How to change the logo size in Docusaurus?

Tags: customization, docusaurus

How to change the logo height on docusaurus? I've tried various things but no luck

Changing the css to navbar__brand and set the height on the image it self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been struggling with the same issue. Here's what seems to work for me.

In your `src/css/custom.css` file:

```
.navbar__logo img {
  height: 160%;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

I also set the `navbar-height` as I wanted it a little bigger. This is in the same `src/css/custom.css` file.

```
:root {
  ...
  --ifm-navbar-height: 80px;
}
```

You can play around with the `height` and/or `margin-top` and it should work. Seems ok for scaling with the page as well.

There may be a better way, but was not able to find it documented. Setting the `height/width` in the `navbar.logo` object of `docusaurus.config.json` did not work, or messed up the image scaling.

Comment: Awesome! It made the difference!

Answer (score 1):

In the docusaurus.config.js file, locate the navbar section. There should be a logo field that specifies the logo image file.

Add a height field to the logo object and set it to the desired height of the logo, in pixels.

```
module.exports = {
  navbar: {
    logo: {
      src: '/img/logo.png',
      height: 40,
    },
    // ...
  },
  // ...
};
```

Try this out , It should work

Comment: My config.js file is the "default", and contains:
module.exports = config;
 and under themeConfig:
navbar: {
        logo: {
          alt: 'My Site Logo',
          src: 'img/logo.svg',
          height: 150,
        },

But does not work :(

Comment: I just tried adding width: 1000 to the logo section, and it applies just fine, but the height property does not.